# Installing TypeScript definitions of mocha fails

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings

I don't quite get this error message and how to fix this.
I'm trying to install the typings definition of `mocha` but all I get is the following error message:

```
$ typings install env~mocha
Attempted to compile "mocha" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install it as a global module (previously called [ambient module](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/343)).

```
$ typings install env~mocha --global
```